# All types have Finalize method inherited from Object?

Tags: c#, .net

We know that when a type override Finalize method, it must survive the garbage collection, it gets promoted to another generation, forcing the object to live much longer than it should. This is not ideal in terms of memory consumption and is why you should avoid finalization when possible.

But isn't that all type implicitly derived from `Object`, and `Object` does have a default Finalize method, so CLR should consider all types have Finalize method and therefore all objects on the heap will get prompted to new generation, and live longer than they should?

Comment: From [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.finalize?view=net-5.0#how-finalization-works): "The Object class provides no implementation for the Finalize method, and the garbage collector does not mark types derived from Object for finalization unless they override the Finalize method."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @canton7 said in a comment, the runtime is smart enough to know that if there are no finalizers in the instance's inheritance chain other than `Object.Finalize` then it does not have to mark the instance for finalization. The relevant part of [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.finalize?view=net-5.0#how-finalization-works) is:

> The `Object` class provides no implementation for the `Finalize` method, and the garbage collector does not mark types derived from `Object` for finalization unless they override the `Finalize` method.

Interestingly enough, neither [the C# specification](https://github.com/dotnet/csharpstandard/blob/5835a68e85e12016da956cbb59b689c22e4da21e/standard/classes.md#1513-finalizers) nor [the ECMA CLI specification](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications-and-standards/standards/ecma-335/) enforce this behaviour. It is permitted for a conforming implementation of the runtime to always schedule all objects for finalization. However, as you recognised in the question, this would cause an enormous overhead in garbage collection so it would be impractical.

---

Note: the relevant sections are §8.9 and §15.2 for the C# spec and I.8.9.6.7 of the ECMA CLI spec.

Comment: ([Link to the actual doc pages, rather than GitHub](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/classes#destructors))

Comment: @canton7 I'd argue that C# 6.0 spec draft is the de facto up-to-date version of the spec, but in this case they differ only in naming finalizer vs destructor anyway.

Comment: I linked to MSDN because the GitHub docs have a have a habit of moving around (particularly as you linked to a branch name, rather than pressing `y` and getting a better identifier). In particular, I'd expect that doc to move when the C# 6 spec gets out of draft. I figured the MSDN link was likely longer-lived

Comment: @canton7 TIL pressing `y` on GitHub gives you the SHA link.